# How can I convince Coq that my function is in fact recursive?

Tags: recursion, coq, termination

I'm trying to write a program in Coq to parse a relatively simple context-free grammar (one type of parenthesis) and my general algorithm is for the parser to potentially return the remainder of a string. For example, parsing `"++]>><<"` should return `CBTerminated [Incr Incr] ">><<"` and then, say a parser that is parsing "[++]>><<" would be able to pick up the ">><<" and continue with that.

So obviously, the string is smaller, but convincing Coq of that is another matter. It is giving me the error

> Recursive definition of parseHelper is ill-formed. [...] Recursive call to parseHelper has principal argument equal to "rest'" instead
>   of "rest".

Which I assume means that it isn't convinced that `rest' < input` in the way that it's convinced that `rest < input`. (where `<` means "is smaller than").

I'd thought of instead returning a count of how many characters to skip, but that seems rather inelegant and uneccessary.

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.
Require Import Coq.Strings.Ascii.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope char_scope.
Open Scope list_scope.

Notation " [ ] " := nil (format "[ ]") : list_scope.
Notation " [ x ] " := (cons x nil) : list_scope.
Notation " [ x ; y ; .. ; z ] " := (cons x (cons y .. (cons z nil) ..)) : list_scope.

Inductive BF :=
    | Incr : BF
    | Decr : BF
    | Left : BF
    | Right : BF
    | In : BF
    | Out : BF
    | Sequence : list BF -> BF
    | While : BF -> BF.

Inductive BF_Parse_Result :=
    | UnmatchedOpen
    | EOFTerminated (u : list BF)
    | CBTerminated (u : list BF) (rest : string).

Definition bind (val : BF) (onto : BF_Parse_Result) :=
    match onto with
        | UnmatchedOpen => UnmatchedOpen
        | EOFTerminated values => EOFTerminated (cons val values)
        | CBTerminated values rest => CBTerminated (cons val values) rest
    end.

Fixpoint parseHelper (input : string) : BF_Parse_Result :=
    match input with
        | EmptyString => EOFTerminated nil
        | String first rest =>
             match first with
                 | "+" => bind Incr (parseHelper rest)
                 | "-" => bind Decr (parseHelper rest)
                 | "<" => bind Left (parseHelper rest)
                 | ">" => bind Right (parseHelper rest)
                 | "," => bind In (parseHelper rest)
                 | "." => bind Out (parseHelper rest)
                 | "]" => CBTerminated nil rest
                 | "[" =>
                     match parseHelper rest with
                         | UnmatchedOpen => UnmatchedOpen
                         | EOFTerminated _ => UnmatchedOpen
                         | CBTerminated vals rest' =>
                             bind (While (Sequence vals)) (parseHelper rest')
                     end
                 | _ => parseHelper rest
             end
    end.
```

Comment: Umm, that one is usually tricky. As a first attempt, I suggest you define your function by recursion on the numbers of calls. That is to say, add a nat parameter that limits how many times the function is called. But `parseHelper (length input) input` will be correct. Once you get that form working, you could start to refactor (maybe using an accumulator?) See: https://x80.org/collacoq/abidadadol.coq

Comment: @ejgallego I tried that but found it very difficult to prove that `parseHelper (length input) input` was in fact correct.

Comment: Umm, it shouldn't be more difficult than proving the version you posted correct, would it be accepted by Coq. You may want a lemma thou stating that the result of parsing is the same for sizes greater than `lenght input` or switch to returning some sizes to have exact values, but you didn't want that.

Comment: Yeah, in particular, for the given definition, you need to generalize the correctness lemma  to `forall n, length input <= n, "correct" parseHelper n input` to get an usable induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you considered using [well-founded recursion](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.GeneralRec.html)? Coq's standard library has a series of useful combinators for defining functions over well-founded relations. Reference [1](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.GeneralRec.html) shows two techniques (well-founded recursion and a monad) for general recursion.

Other technique that is also very useful in context of Agda, is the so-called [Bove-Capretta method](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszvc/publications/General_Recursion_MSCS_2005.pdf), which defines an inductive predicate that mimics the call graph of defined function.

Coq also has the [Function](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/gallina-ext.html#Function) command that can be used to define more general recursive functions. Whenever I needed to define non-structurally recursive functions, I have used well-founded recursion.

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this interesting strategy.

In my case, I ended up just refactoring to a different design that uses an explicit stack of all the open parentheses at a given point, I think I just taill-call-eliminated it, it's a little simpler.

Comment: For completeness, `Program Fixpoint` can be used quite the same way as `Function` to deal with non-structural recursion.